# Java Create a Directory that does not exist

Tags: java

I am currently working on RecycleBin component for a file management server. When a document gets deleted all versions get deleted from multiple locations. When this occurs all folder paths get deleted to a repeating string dp_original_folder_paths.

I want to creat the folder path when it doesnt exist.

Here is my current code. The first part checks if file exists if not creates it. The second part shows the document being relinked to folder.

```
for (int i = 0;
            i < relationRecord.getValueCount("dp_original_folder_paths"); i++)
            {
                File f = new File(relationRecord.getRepeatingString(
                        "dp_original_folder_paths",
                        i));

                if(!f.exists())
                {
                    System.out.println("creating directory" + f);
                    f.mkdir();
                }
// Link the document back to the original folders

    for (int i = 0; i < relationRecord.getValueCount("dp_original_folder_paths")
                i++)
     {

    document.link(
        relationRecord.getRepeatingString("dp_original_folder_paths", i));

    }
```

The output given is

creating directory: \EAM\sbotest

DIR created

Linked to /EAM/sbotest

DfPathNotFoundException:: THREAD: http-bio-8080-exec-7; MSG: [DM_API_E_EXIST]err
or:  "Folder specified by /EAM/sbotest does not exist."; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null

Does anyone know why in the first println the output is \EAM\sbotest and the second output the \ become /  /EAM/sbotest

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to create a folder on the filesystem or in documentum?

Comment: I am trying to create it in Webtop the web interface for documentum.

Answer (score 2):

since Java 1.7 it's recommended to use

```
Files.createDirectories(new File("C:/dir1/dir2/dir3/").toPath());
```

[Files (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `f.mkdirs()` to create parent directories as well.
`f.mkdir()` will only try to create the last child directory, parent ones must exist.

Comment: Switched it to f.mkdirs(); but still no luck. Is a Dir d = new Dir in java or a folder instead of File?

Comment: Then probably the path is not correct (/ at the beggining for windows), or you do not have permission to create the folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [File#mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())?

It will create the directory and any non-existent parent directories for you.